# How to make the setInterval stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have already tried `clearInterval()`, I also tried to make a variable equal to the `var somevariable = setInterval(somefunction,sometime)` and then making `clearInterval(somevariable)`.

I want it to stop the timer when I press the button(reset). There are lot of similar question on stackoverflow but none of the answers worked for me.

```
var workTime = 0;
var breakTime = 0;
var breakMinutes = 0;
var breakSeconds = 0;
var sessionHour = 0;
var sessionMinutes = 0;
var sessionSeconds = 0;
var pemaBreakMinutes = 0;
var permaSessionHour = 0;
var permaSessionMinutes = 0;
var check = 0;

// Increasing Work Time
function setWorkTimePlus() {
   $("#workPlus").click(function() {
      if (workTime < 60) {
         workTime = workTime + 5;
         sessionMinutes = sessionMinutes + 5;
         $("#workTime").text(workTime);
         $("#sessionMinutes").text(workTime);
      }
      if (workTime === 60) {
         sessionHour = sessionHour + 1;
         workTime = 0;
         sessionMinutes = 0;
         $("#sessionHours").text(sessionHour);
         $("#workTime").text(workTime);
         $("#sessionMinutes").text(sessionMinutes);
      };
   });
};
// Decrease Work Time
function setWorkTimeMinus() {
   $("#workMinus").click(function() {
      if (workTime > 0) {
         workTime = workTime - 5;
         sessionMinutes = sessionMinutes - 5;
         $("#workTime").text(workTime);
         $("#sessionMinutes").text(workTime);
      };
      if (workTime === 0 && sessionHour > 0) {
         sessionHour = sessionHour - 1;
         workTime = 60;
         sessionMinutes = 60;
         $("#sessionHours").text(sessionHour);
         $("#workTime").text(workTime);
         $("#sessionMinutes").text(sessionMinutes);
      };
   });
};
// Increase Break Time
function setBreakTimePlus() {
   $("#breakPlus").click(function() {
      if (breakTime < 60) {
         breakTime = breakTime + 5;
         breakMinutes = breakMinutes + 5;
         $("#breakTime").text(breakTime);
      };
   });
};
// Decrease Break Time
function setBreakTimeMinus() {
   $("#breakMinus").click(function() {
      if (breakTime > 0) {
         breakTime = breakTime - 5;
         breakMinutes = breakMinutes - 5;
         $("#breakTime").text(breakTime);
      };
   });
};
// Process of decreasing seconds, Minutes and Hours and then initiating Break Timer
function working() {
   if (sessionSeconds > 0) {
      sessionSeconds = sessionSeconds - 1;
      $("#sessionSeconds").text(sessionSeconds);
   }
   if (sessionSeconds === 0 && sessionMinutes > 0) {
      sessionMinutes = sessionMinutes - 1;
      sessionSeconds = 60;
      $("#sessionMinutes").text(sessionMinutes);
   }
   if (sessionMinutes === 0 && sessionHour > 0) {
      sessionHour = sessionHour - 1;
      sessionMinutes = 60;
      $("#sessionHours").text(sessionHour);
      $("#sessionMinutes").text(sessionMinutes);
   }
   if (breakSeconds > 0 && sessionSeconds === 0 && sessionMinutes === 0 && sessionHour === 0) {
      $("#sessionH").text("Break Time");
      breakSeconds = breakSeconds - 1;
      $("#sessionSeconds").text(breakSeconds);
      $("#sessionMinutes").text(breakMinutes);
   }
   if (breakSeconds === 0 && breakMinutes > 0 && sessionSeconds === 0) {
      breakMinutes = breakMinutes - 1;
      breakSeconds = 60;
      $("#sessionMinutes").text(breakMinutes);
   }
   if (breakSeconds > 0 && sessionSeconds === 0 && sessionMinutes === 0 && sessionHour === 0 && breakMinutes === 0) {
      sessionMinutes = permaSessionMinutes;
      sessionSeconds = 0;
      sessionHours = permaSessionHour;
      breakMinutes = pemaBreakMinutes;
      breakSeconds = 0;
      $("#sessionHours").text(sessionHour);
      $("#sessionMinutes").text(sessionMinutes);
      $("#sessionH").text("Session Time");
   }
};
// Invoking the above function every one second to decrease seconds timely
function startWorkingAndStop() {
   $("#sessionTime").click(function() {
      if (check <= 0) {
         check++;
      permaSessionMinutes = sessionMinutes;
      permaSessionHour = sessionHour;
      pemaBreakMinutes = breakMinutes;
      $("#setWorkTime,#setBreakTime").slideUp(1000);
      $("#sessionTime").css('border', '0px');
      setInterval(working, 1000);
      };
   });
};

function nukeIt() {
   $("#reset").click(function() {
      if (check > 0) {
         $("#setWorkTime,#setBreakTime").slideDown(1000);
         $("#sessionTime").css({
            "border-top": "2px solid black",
            "border-bottom": "2px solid black"
         });
         check = 0;
         workTime = 0;
         breakTime = 0;
         breakMinutes = 0;
         breakSeconds = 0;
         sessionHour = 0;
         sessionMinutes = 0;
         sessionSeconds = 0;
         pemaBreakMinutes = 0;
         permaSessionHour = 0;
         permaSessionMinutes = 0;
         $("#workTime").text(workTime);
         $("#breakTime").text(breakTime);
         $("#sessionMinutes").text(sessionMinutes);
         $("#sessionSeconds").text(sessionSeconds);
         $("#sessionHours").text(sessionHour);
      }
   });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
   setWorkTimePlus();
   setWorkTimeMinus();
   setBreakTimePlus();
   setBreakTimeMinus();
   startWorkingAndStop();
   nukeIt();
});
```

---

You could also check it out on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Lavios/pen/wKjMYZ). You can start the timer by clicking on the timer, after you've set the break and the work time.

**If you want, you can ignore the question below, I will select the answer on the question above**

If you visit, could you also help me make the text " HOURS MINUTES SECONDS" responsive to the 00:00:00, I can't figure it out, I've tried flexbox and just regular css.

Comment: *"I also tried to make a variable equal to the var somevariable = setInterval(somefunction,sometime) and then making clearInterval(somevariable)."* That is the solution, so you likely just implemented it incorrectly. Showing your attempt might help us figure out why.

Comment: @KevinB - I just tried it again. It worked. I don't know what I did wrong the last time. Thanks!! Updated it on CodePen

Comment: Questions about debugging on Stack Overflow require a [mcve]. The code that you have posted is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to ensure that the code **in your question** is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more). As it is your question is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

`clearInterval()` **is** the correct way to stop an interval. What may be your problem is **scope**. If you are defining your variable inside one of your jQuery async calls, but you don't keep a reference to it in the parent, you won't be able to reference it again.

Here's an example using the above principle:

```
var interval;
var on;

$(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){

        if(on == "1")
        {
            clearInterval(interval);
            on = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            interval = setInterval(function(){

                $("div").html((parseInt($("div").html()) + 1));

            });

            on = "1";
        }
    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3ue6ow0/)

Answer (score 0):

setInterval returns a unique identifier for the specific interval event you created. Using clearInterval with that unique identifier as a parameter should cancel the event.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Do **not** use this. use @David's answer instead. It is much, much better.

<strike>You could use</strike>

```
setTimeout(...)
```

instead of

```
setInterval(...)
```

Use it like this:

```
var loop = function() {
    /* The code you want to do */
    if (/* Condition */) {
        setTimeout(loop, /* Time in MS. */)
    }
};
loop();
```

it is not really nice, but it works.

Comment: Yes this works but like David answered the clearInterval is the right way to do this.

Also I think there is potential problem that continuous interval is possible (unlike solution like this) to implement so that its quaranteed: N * interval_times the function is always hitted N times and contains only temporary errors but solution like this may increse invoke count error over time on long run. Error may be tiny and meaningless on most use cases but still.

But if there is "lazy" implementation under browsers there might be no difrence at all...

Answer (score -1):

take a look at the code pen I helped you with minutes formating to always 00 you can try with hours.

```
$("#sessionMinutes").text('0'+workTime);
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvapeq)

Comment: what's wrong with the answer for downvoting ?